# Salesforce - export BULK UserRecordAccess

Tags: salesforce, apex, force.com

I'm looking for a way to answer the question "what records does user XYZ have access to" - via the API or some feature that doesn't require the user to be logged in. Example: from an Administrative standpoint I want to see all my 250 users and the specific accounts that each has access to, including (if possible) the access level (r, r/w, c, d).  Priority is read access though...what they "see".

Essentially I'm looking for a way to bulk export the UserRecordAccess "view" for a specific user which I specify, bypassing the 200 limit which requires record ID's to be provided.

This needs to be programmatic because I have to get it into a 3rd party compliance system.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.  I ended up reverse engineering SF's security model, pulling everything from roles, to groups, to criteria based sharing out.